# Relative paths in twig or absolute in PhpStorm

Tags: twig, phpstorm

I'm new to `twig`. I'm using it in PhpStorm and have problem with paths.

Here is my folder structure:

```
- template /folder/
    - main.twig
    - common /folder/
        - bootstrap.twig
        - nav.twig
```

In  `main.twig` I have code:

```
{% extends "common/bootstrap.twig" %}
```

When I <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on link PhpStorm opens correct file.

But in `bootstrap.twig` I have to write:

```
{% include "common/nav.twig" %}
```

and then <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> is not working.
I cannot use relative paths like `nav.twig` or `./nav.twig` - twig throws error.

How can I make twig to use relative paths so go to source would work in PhpStorm?

Comment: Try the most obvious: mark your `template` folder as Resource Root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark your template root folder (`template` in your case) as **Resource Root** (either via right click in Project View or via `Settings/Preferences | Directories`).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html?search=directories

> Files under a folder marked as Resource Root can be referenced relative to this folder.